# Why would this work - making the OS pointing to Emacs GUI app instead of the default one?

Tags: emacs

I have emacs on OS X that comes pre-installed, and is found in `/usr/bin/emacs`. It does not allow me to run it as a bg process (using &) and does not present me with a nice GUI.

I therefore installed the GUI package of emacs, which gets installed in `/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS` - the executable name is `Emacs`.

I want my OS X to always point to `/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs` instead of `/usr/bin/emacs`. I updated my `.profile` and added the path of graphical Emacs to the PATH.

Now if I run `which emacs`, it results in:

```
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/emacs
```

1. Why would this work? Why is the Emacs GUI app now used instead of the pre-installed one?
2. Why is the system printing 'emacs' in lowercase while the actual application name starts with an upper case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. From the [Wikipedia page on PATH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29):

   > When a command name is specified by the user or an exec call is made from a program, the system searches the path, examining each directory from left to right in the list, looking for a filename that matches the command name. Once found, the program is executed as a child process of the command shell or program that issued the command.
2. The default Mac OSX file system is [case-insensitive by default](http://davidwinter.me/articles/2008/05/17/mac-os-xhfs-case-insensitive-why/). That is, there is no distinction between `/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs` and `/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/emacs`.